# Matching on Values, but Erroring on New Value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server-2005

I am comparing data from two different databases (one MariaDB and one SQL Server) within my Node project, and am then doing inserts and updates as necessary depending on the comparison results.

I have a question about this code that I use to iterate through results in Node, going one at a time and passing in values to check against (note - I am more familiar with Node and JS than with SQL, hence this question):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    CASE 
       WHEN RM00101.CUSTCLAS LIKE ('%CUSR%') 
          THEN CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(LR301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LR301.DOCNUMBR)), '-', '') AS INT) 
          ELSE 0 
    END AS Id,
    CASE 
       WHEN LR301.RMDTYPAL = 7 THEN LR301.ORTRXAMT * -1
       WHEN LR301.RMDTYPAL = 9 THEN LR301.ORTRXAMT * -1
       ELSE LR301.ORTRXAMT
    END DocumentAmount,
    GETDATE() VerifyDate
FROM
    CRDB..RM20101
INNER JOIN 
    CRDB..RM00101 ON LR301.CUSTNMBR = RM00101.CUSTNMBR
WHERE 
    CONVERT(BIGINT, (REPLACE(LEFT(LR301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LR301.DOCNUMBR)), '-', ''))) = 589091
```

Currently, the above works for me for finding records that match. However, if I enter a value that doesn't yet exist - in this line below, like so:

```
WHERE CONVERT(BIGINT, (REPLACE(LEFT( LR301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LR301.DOCNUMBR)), '-', ''))) = 789091
```

I get this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

I assume the issue is that, if the value isn't found, it can't cast it to an INTEGER, and so it errors out. Sound right?

What I ideally want is for the query to execute successfully, but just return 0 results when a match is not found. In JavaScript I might doing something like an `OR` clause to handle this:

```
const array = returnResults || [];
```

But I'm not sure how to handle this with SQL.

By the way, the value in SQL Server that's being matched is of type `char(21)`, and the values look like this: `00000516542-000`. The value in MariaDB is of type `INT`.

So two questions:

1. Will this error out when I enter a value that doesn't currently match?
2. If so, how can I handle this so as to just return 0 rows when a match isn't found?

By the way, as an added note, someone suggested using `TRY_CONVERT`, but while this works in SQL Server, it doesn't work when I use it with the NODE `mssql` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is happening because the varchar value is not always made of numbers. You can make the comparison in varchar format itself to avoid this issue:

```
WHERE (REPLACE(LEFT( LR301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LR301.DOCNUMBR)), '-', '')) = '789091'
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: based on the format in the comment, this should do the trick;

```
WHERE REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT( LR301.DOCNUMBR, CHARINDEX('-', LR301.DOCNUMBR)),'0',' '),'-','')),' ','0') = '789091'
```

Comment: Isn't the issue that, if the value isn't found, it can't cast it to an INTEGER, and so it errors out?

Comment: The left side of the comparison tries to extract a certain section of the value from a varchar value. If the extracted value is all numbers, then the conversion to int would work, otherwise it wouldn't

Comment: The comparison is made after the conversion, so the failure is happening before that. Comparing in varchar should fix this

Comment: When I try this it looks like it doesn't return the value when it is found. So it prevents the error, but doesn't find the value when it does exist?

Comment: Can you share the entire string for LR301.DOCNUMBR for this ID '789091'. I think the issue is with the left side of the comparison

Comment: The values look like this: `00000516542-000      ` It is of type char(21).

Comment: The left calculation was not doing the trick. I have added an edit to the answer, that should give the desired result

Comment: I don't see the actual value to be evaluated - `789091` - in your updated code?

Comment: Didn't add it before, since the change was only in the left side...Updated it to show the entire thing now

Comment: Okay, tried that, thanks. Got this: `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
`

Comment: It usually involves a bit of trial and error. Updated the answer to fix the above error

Comment: Looks like that worked! Many thanks, @CR7SMS. By the way, not sure if this is relevant to your avatar, but Messi's better. ;)

Comment: Haha...I know he is...But that's not going to stop me from rooting for CR7 ;)